# Find & replace inside a compiled HTML file using Laravel Mix

Tags: webpack, webpack-4, laravel-mix

I am using the `laravel-mix-criticalcss` extension to generate an HTML file. Once that file is compiled, I need to run a find and replace in the HTML file source code to rewrite the URLs from relative to absolute. I tried using `laravel-mix-string-replace`, which uses `string-replace-loader,` but the replace never happens. I must be missing something with the way the webpack works. What am I missing?

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const glob = require("glob");

require('laravel-mix-criticalcss');
require('laravel-mix-string-replace');

mix.setPublicPath('assets')
    .disableNotifications()
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false
    });

mix.criticalCss({
    enabled: true,
    paths: {
        base: 'http://lpb-cms.devel',
        templates: 'assets/css/',
        suffix: ''
    },
    urls: [
        {url: '/lpb-branding/get-header/', template: 'header-footer'},
    ],
    options: {
        minify: false,
        height: 19200,
        dest: 'header-footer.html',
        inline: true
    },
}).stringReplace({
    test: /\.html$/,
    loader: 'string-replace-loader',
    options: {
        search: '/themes/',
        replace: 'https://lpb-cms-dev.purecobalt.com/themes/',
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `laravel-mix-string-replace` package doesn't seem to work.

You can use the `mix.after()` method like this:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

mix.setPublicPath('assets')
    .disableNotifications()
    .options({
        processCssUrls: false
    });

mix.criticalCss({
    enabled: true,
    paths: {
        base: 'http://lpb-cms.devel',
        templates: 'assets/css/',
        suffix: ''
    },
    urls: [
        {url: '/lpb-branding/get-header/', template: 'header-footer'},
    ],
    options: {
        minify: false,
        height: 19200,
        dest: 'header-footer.html',
        inline: true
    },
}).after(stats => {
    // webpack compilation has completed
    fs.readFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'header-footer.html'), 'utf8' , (readError, data) => {
        if (readError) {
            console.error("\x1b[31mError: \x1b[0m" + readError);
            return;
        }

        var result = data.replace('/themes/', 'https://lpb-cms-dev.purecobalt.com/themes/');

        fs.writeFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'header-footer.html'), result, writeError => {
            if (writeError) {
                console.error("\x1b[31mError: \x1b[0m" + writeError);
                return;
            }

            console.log("Relative theme directory references replaced to full urls!");
        });
    })
})
```

If you need to replace more than one thing, you can chain the replacements:

```js
var result = data.replace('foo', 'bar').replace('this', 'that');
```